# Passing Boolean prop results in Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "value"

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vuetify.js

I'm attempting to pass a boolean value from Vuex store as a prop into a component to control the visibility on an alert. I pass the prop to the alerts `value` property.

The result is the error:

`[Vue warn]: Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "value". Expected Boolean, got String with value "globalAlert.alert".`

I've adjusted how I pass the to the component a few different ways, removes parens, etc. But it appears to be taking my globalAlert as a literal String, even though I've validated that the Vuex getter is returning the `globalAlert` error properly.

**Implementation**

This store controls the global alert state

```
const state = {
    globalAlert: {
        alert: false,
        alertTitle: "",
        alertMessage: ""
    }
}

const getters = {
    getGlobalAlert: state => state.globalAlert
}

const actions = {
    setGlobalAlert({ commit }, error) {
        commit('setAlert', error)
    }
}

const mutations = {
    setAlert: (state, globalAlert) => (state.globalAlert = globalAlert)
}

export default {
    state,
    getters,
    actions,
    mutations
}
```

This is alert component with `globalAlert` prop

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <v-app id="inspire">
      <div>
        <v-alert
          value="globalAlert.alert"
          dismissible
          color="red"
          transition="slide-y-transition"
          dark
          dense
          border="left"
          elevation="2"
          class="ma-5"
          icon="error"
        >
          Something bad just happened
        </v-alert>

        <div class="text-center">
          <v-btn v-if="!alert" dark @click="alert = true">Reset Alert</v-btn>
        </div>
      </div>
    </v-app>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "GlobalAlert",
  props: {
    globalAlert: {}
  }
};
</script>
```

This is the usage of the component, where globalAlert is pulled from the store and sent down to the component

```
...
<GlobalAlert 
    :globalAlert="globalAlert">
</GlobalAlert>
...
import { mapGetters, mapActions } from "vuex";
import GlobalAlert from "../components/GlobalAlert";
...
components: {GlobalAlert},
computed: {
    ...mapGetters(["isAuthenticated", "userDetails", "getGlobalError"]),
    globalAlert(){
        return this.$store.state.error.globalAlert; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you try setting `value` to `v-value`? (or to `v-bind:value`)

Comment: The result of doing so is a different error, `vue.runtime.esm.js:619 [Vue warn]: Failed to resolve directive: value. `
I've also cleaned up the btn that referenced 'alert', which should not have been there.

Comment: `value="globalAlert.alert"` should be `:value="globalAlert.alert"`, where the `:` prefix is a shorthand for `v-bind:`.